# How do I include all children of a DOM element to be dragged using the Sortable plugin for MooTools?

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, mootools-more, mootools-sortable

I am using `mootools-more.1817.js`...this is my HTML structure:

```html
<ul id="categories">
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Top Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/3">Link 2</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/2">Link 3</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/4">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Lame Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/9">Link 9</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/10">Link 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Awesome Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/11">Link 11</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/12">Link 12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I want to do two things:

1. Be able to drag each `li` item to another section and have it take all its children with it. E.g. if I am dragging the li that has the link `Top Links`, I want to drag not only the words `Top Links`, but also the `div#admin`, `ul` and `li` that are children of that parent `li`. Essentially all the children of each `li`.
2. I would also like to be able to drag items between lists of the children. So for instance, say I want to drag the link `Link 2` from that `ul` to the section called `Awesome Links` and drop it between the links `Link 11` and `Link 12`.

I have done this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Sortables('#categories', {
        clone: true,
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.7  
    });
});
```

What that does is drags JUST the `li`, and not the children of the `li`.

How do I achieve those?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have invalid HTML by having `div` items in your `categories` list that are not in `li` tags themselves. The only immediate children to a `ul` can be `li` for a valid list.

Second, according to the documentation, "To enable sorting between lists, one or more lists or id's must be passed using an array or a selector" (http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Sortables). That means, to move items between your sublists, each `ul` must be passed into a sortables group (different than the categories group). This should solve your issue #2.

I'm not yet sure why it would not drag the whole contents of the `li`, though it may be the invalid HTML is causing issues.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with MooTools sortable. I am trying out something else written by a core supporter: http://cpojer.net/PowerTools/

Comment: `POWERTOOLS!` is also not written for 1.12. have fun