# How do I get the 'PowerTools' plugin to work for MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-more

Specifically, I am trying to use the `Tree` functionality, as can be seen here: 
http://cpojer.net/MooTools/tree/Demos/#  The source can be seen here:
https://github.com/cpojer/mootools-tree/blob/master/README.md

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Top Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/3">Link 2</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/2">Link 3</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/4">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Lame Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/9">Link 9</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/10">Link 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <div id="admin">Admin Controls</div>
    <li><a href="#">Awesome Links</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="article"><a href="/11">Link 11</a></li>
            <li id="article"><a href="/12">Link 12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have added the `Tree.js` to my `mootools.js` core file.

This is my JS call:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
       var tree = new Tree('#tree');
        tree.serialize();
});
```

As is, the sorting of the tree doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: I tried doing this with Sortable for regular MooTools More, but I don't think I can do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282636/how-do-i-include-all-children-of-a-dom-element-to-be-dragged-using-the-sortable

Comment: Just posted a new answer to an old question... it might be useful for some one else.

Answer (score 1):

In the instantiation, you are passing a selector "#tree. If the tree class expects an ID, you don't use a pound sign, just "tree". In MooTools, there is a $ fn for ID lookups and a $$ fn for full selector lookups, there are various reasons they chose to separate the two.

Comment: The weirdest thing is, I changed it...and it still doesn't work. I no longer get the error about 'Tree' being an `UnReferenced Error`. But, it just doesn't work...and I am not sure why. I have all the mootools files included on the page working properly (mootools core, mootools more, mootools class extras, and power tools). Do I need anything else?

Comment: Can you build a quick example in jsFiddle, this is hard to debug without seeing live.

Comment: Ok I got it working, kinda: http://jsfiddle.net/VquhK/8/

Now the question is, how do I get it to work with the `divs` inside the `ul`. E.g., when I move `Test`, how do I let it move the `div` and text `Admin Controls` right above it, altogether?

Comment: So you want the element containing the text "Admin Controls" in your example on jsFiddle to essentially come with any selected group of draggable elements you choose to move?

Answer (score 0):

Found this question and thought about answering.
A bit late though, but I was not member on SO when you asked this question :)

What I changed to put this working:

- You need to pass just `tree`, the ID without the `#`.
- Your tree has to have only `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, otherwise tree.js will not be able to drag them over normal divs.
- You need [**unique**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687) ID's, I renamed all you `id="admin"` to `class="admin"` instead.

So you can use the javascript/mootools like:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
       var tree = new Tree('tree');
        tree.serialize();
});
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tgaQj/)**